# IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred)

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, ignite

When IgniteBean with SSL enabled is injected in Spring boot AsyncConfigurer, the application is breaking. If I use Ignite without AsyncConfigurer, It works fine. Below is the error log:

```
[18:48:37] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
2020-04-21T13:18:37.955+0000 [main] ERROR [IgniteKernal]  - Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).

org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.create(SslContextFactory.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.create(SslContextFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.resetNioServer(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2555)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.getNodeAttributes(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2310)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.start(GridIoManager.java:435)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1960)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:637)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:563)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:321)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration.ignite(IgniteBeanConfiguration.java:103)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14bb67ab.CGLIB$ignite$0(<generated>)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14bb67ab$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cbb5577b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14bb67ab.ignite(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.itron.boot.ItronSpringApplication.run(ItronSpringApplication.java:107)
    at com.itron.boot.ItronSpringApplication.run(ItronSpringApplication.java:94)
    at com.itron.dicd.DICodeDeployerService.main(DICodeDeployerService.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:470)
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.createSslContext(SslContextFactory.java:338)
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.create(SslContextFactory.java:516)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:783)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:457)
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:781)
    ... 96 common frames omitted

2020-04-21T13:18:37.974+0000 [main]  WARN [IgniteKernal]  - Attempt to stop starting grid. This operation cannot be guaranteed to be successful.
[18:48:38] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:01.771]
2020-04-21T13:18:38.025+0000 [main]  WARN [AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext]  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dicdAsyncConfigurer' defined in file [/home/arani/itron/dicodedeployer/service/target/classes/com/itron/dicd/config/DicdAsyncConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [com/itron/dicd/config/IgniteBeanConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
2020-04-21T13:18:38.124+0000 [main] ERROR [SpringApplication]  - Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dicdAsyncConfigurer' defined in file [/home/arani/itron/dicodedeployer/service/target/classes/com/itron/dicd/config/DicdAsyncConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [com/itron/dicd/config/IgniteBeanConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:676)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.itron.boot.ItronSpringApplication.run(ItronSpringApplication.java:107)
    at com.itron.boot.ItronSpringApplication.run(ItronSpringApplication.java:94)
    at com.itron.dicd.DICodeDeployerService.main(DICodeDeployerService.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dicdAsyncConfigurer' defined in file [/home/arani/itron/dicodedeployer/service/target/classes/com/itron/dicd/config/DicdAsyncConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [com/itron/dicd/config/IgniteBeanConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [com/itron/dicd/config/IgniteBeanConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.create(SslContextFactory.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory.create(SslContextFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.resetNioServer(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2555)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.getNodeAttributes(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2310)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.start(GridIoManager.java:435)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1960)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:637)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:563)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:321)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration.ignite(IgniteBeanConfiguration.java:103)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14bb67ab.CGLIB$ignite$0(<generated>)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14bb67ab$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cbb5577b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at com.itron.dicd.config.IgniteBeanConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14bb67ab.ignite(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project dicodedeployer-service: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dicdAsyncConfigurer' defined in file [/home/arani/itron/dicodedeployer/service/target/classes/com/itron/dicd/config/DicdAsyncConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [com/itron/dicd/config/IgniteBeanConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.*BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize key store (I/O error occurred): /home/arani/itron/thirdparty/certs/dicodedeployer.jks: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect: Password verification failed -> [Help 1]*
```

There is no problem with username/password of Keystore.

SSL IgniteBeanConfiguration:

```
@Nonnull
    private SslContextFactory buildSSLContextFactory()
    {
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreFilePath(serverProperties.getSsl().getKeyStore());
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(serverProperties.getSsl().getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
        sslContextFactory.setTrustManagers(SslContextFactory.getDisabledTrustManager());
        return sslContextFactory;
    }
```

Please help me to figure out the issue.
Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: There should be "caused by" block to that exception, can you add it?

Comment: @alamar I have added the "caused by" block.